# Source bash script when starting midnight commander

Tags: bash, command-line, mc

Is there a way to source some bash script when I run command `mc`? I want to have it sourced in the bash instance of midnight commander. I tried something like this

```
mc && . .bash_script.sh
```

and it doesn't work. It seems like Bash sourced the script in previous Bash instance because after running `exit` command I see that `.bash_script.sh` was sourced. But in midning commander's command line it's not available.

Comment: can you give us an idea as to what the script is actually doing?

Comment: It starts bash git-prompt https://github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt. I have this piece of code in .bash_login. 

if [ -f ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh ]; then
    . ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh
fi

Answer (score 1):

`man mc`, search for "**bashrc**" keyword:

> If  you are using bash you can specify startup commands for the
>   subshell in your ~/.local/share/mc/**bashrc** file and special keyboard
>   maps in    the ~/.local/share/mc/inputrc file.  tcsh users may specify
>   startup commands in the ~/.local/share/mc/tcshrc file.

So, assume `~/.bash_script.sh` is the path of your `.bash_script.sh`, add `~/.local/share/mc/bashrc` file with this content:

```
[xiaobai@localhost tmp]$ cat ~/.local/share/mc/bashrc
. ~/.bash_script.sh
[xiaobai@localhost tmp]$
```

After issue `mc` (or `mc -U`), the bottom command prompt will change to current time.

Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> to go inside subshell, the gray color+git info will take effect only after you issue first command here (bug). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>o</kbd> again to go back `mc` main screen.

Comment: It worked to add my code into ~/.local/share/mc/bashrc. Thx for your suggestion. Bad thing is that gitprompt doesn't work. However it was sourced from . ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh;. But prompt in shell is gray(not colorized) and it doesn't contain information about changes in repo. :(

Comment: @user5587353 You need `Ctrl-o` go inside subshell and issue a at least ONE command(e.g. `ls`) to see the effect, and this effect only apply inside subshell session, not `mc` main screen.

Comment: I see, prompt is collorized after pressing eg. enter. But It doesn't contains information about changes in repo like [ master | ✔  ]. That's what  github.com/magicmonty/bash-git-prompt doing.

Comment: @user5587353 Are you sure you already `cd` to git project directory ? I have no problem to see `✔ ~/git/android/xxx [master|✚ 5] `

Answer (score 0):

`mc` runs `~/.bashrc`.  So, we can run your `.bash_script.sh` from within `~/.bashrc`.  It sounds like you only want to source the script if you are inside `mc`.  In that case, test for a shell variable that `mc` sets, for example: `MC_SID`.

So, in your `~/.bashrc` add the line:

```
[ "$MC_SID" ] && . .bash_script.sh
```

#### Testing

To verify that this method works, start with something simple.  Put the following line in `~/.bashrc`:

```
[ "$MC_SID" ] && date >>~/mc.log
```

Next, start an instance of `mc`.  Then, run `ls ~/mc.log` to see if this file exists.

Comment: I tried proposed solution but it doesn't work. I have add this piece of code [ "$MC_SID" ] && [ -f ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh ] && {
        GIT_PROMPT_ONLY_IN_REPO=1;
        GIT_PROMPT_THEME=Single_line_Ubuntu;
        . ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh;
}

Comment: @user5587353 For a test case, that is a bit too complex.  Let's start with something simple that we can debug.  I just added a section on _Testing_ to the answer.  Please give it a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: It worked to add my code into ~/.local/share/mc/bashrc. Bad thing is that gitprompt doesn't work. However it was sourced from . ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh;. But prompt in shell is gray(not colorized) and it doesn't contain information about changes in repo. :(

Comment: `mc` does not support colorized prompts.

Comment: I think it's not true, because if I ran . ~/.bash-git-prompt/gitprompt.sh; from shell after I press Ctrl-o. It gives me collorized  prompt.

Comment: Yes, that is true: if you use Ctrol-O to lower the `mc` screen, a colored prompt returns.

Comment: And thats what I want to achieve. To have this colorized prompt right after I start mc.